# What technology can I use for achieving native socket support in Google Chrome apps?

Tags: sockets, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-nativeclient

What technology - **besides NPAPI** - can I use for achieving native socket support in Google Chrome apps?

Flash is not an option, as I assume it requires a policy file.

What about NaCl and/or Pepper?

Comment: Chromium guys are currently integrating a [client socket API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/experimental.socket.html) in Chrome.

Comment: NaCl is not an option either. I has the same security-model as javascript.

Answer (score 0):

No (or at least not yet), because of the web's security model, but you might be interested in workarounds such as [Orbited](http://labs.gameclosure.com/orbited2/).